# How can I filter an object which has a specific key and value out of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my array.

```
const products = [
  {id:1, color:["white","red"], size:["S","M"]},
  {id:2, color:["blue","yellow","white"], size:["S","M","L","XL"]},
  {id:3, color:["green","red"], size:["M"]},
  {id:4, color:["black","green"], size:["L","XL"]},
  {id:5, color:["white","black"], size:["M","L"]},
  {id:6, color:["red","yellow"], size:["S","M"]},
  {id:7, color:["yellow","blue"], size:["L"],
]
```

There are 2 `<Select>` elements for user to select what **color** and **size** they want.
When user select *1 or both* filters those filters are parsed in as an **object**.
Like this:

```
const filters = {color:"red", size:"S"}
```

or *(in case user have selected only 1 filter)*

```
const filters = {color:"red",size:undefined}
```

I want to filter out which objects meet all the criterias and assign that objects to a new **filteredProducts** array.

final output should look like this for the `const filters = {color:"red", size:"S"}` input.

```
const filteredProducts = [
{id:1, color:["white","red"], size:["S","M"]},
{id:6, color:["red","yellow"], size:["S","M"]}
]
```

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Add JavaScript and HTML to your question as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `filter` and `includes` functions as followed:

```js
const products = [
  { id: 1, color: ['white', 'red'], size: ['S', 'M'] },
  { id: 2, color: ['blue', 'yellow', 'white'], size: ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'] },
  { id: 3, color: ['green', 'red'], size: ['M'] },
  { id: 4, color: ['black', 'green'], size: ['L', 'XL'] },
  { id: 5, color: ['white', 'black'], size: ['M', 'L'] },
  { id: 6, color: ['red', 'yellow'], size: ['S', 'M'] },
  { id: 7, color: ['yellow', 'blue'], size: ['L'] },
];

const filters = { color: 'red', size: 'S' };

const filteredProducts = products.filter(
  (e) => e.color.includes(filters.color) && e.size.includes(filters.size)
);

console.log(filteredProducts);
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Is there anyway to do this with using ```Object.entries(filters)```